# pip ContextualVersionConflict when pushing new versions on heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku, pip

I've got this repo, [callisto-core](https://github.com/SexualHealthInnovations/callisto-core) deployed as a [heroku app](http://callisto-core.herokuapp.com/).

It depends on [django-wizard-builder](https://github.com/SexualHealthInnovations/django-wizard-builder) in its [setup.py](https://github.com/SexualHealthInnovations/callisto-core/blob/master/setup.py).

I update `django-wizard-builder` quite frequently, and its started causing installation errors when pushing new versions of `callisto-core`. Specifically, I updated `django-wizard-builder` to version `1.0.5` from `1.0.1` and then pushed to heroku, and got this traceback (formatted for readability)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "{{ PATH }}/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
   status = self.run(options, args)
File "{{ PATH }}/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
   requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
File "{{ PATH }}/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
   ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "{{ PATH }}/pip/req/req_set.py", line 521, in _prepare_file
  req_to_install.check_if_exists()
File "{{ PATH }}/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1036, in check_if_exists
   self.req.name
File "{{ PATH }}/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in get_distribution
   dist = get_provider(dist)
File "{{ PATH }}/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 432, in get_provider
   return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
File "{{ PATH }}/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 968, in require
  needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "{{ PATH }}/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 859, in resolve
  raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (
    django-wizard-builder 1.0.1 ({{ PATH }}),
    Requirement.parse('django-wizard-builder==1.0.5'),
    {'callisto-core'},
)

! Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

I'm getting it on every push that asks for `django-wizard-builder==1.0.5`. I can resolve the issue if I [clear the heroku build cache](https://kb.heroku.com/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache), but I'm not about to do that every time a requirement changes.

I also got this issue on local once, and solved it with `--no-cache-dir --upgrade`, but as far as I can tell I can't set these flags for the heroku install.

This is either a pip issue or a heroku issue or both, and I'm interested in what I can do to fix this and never have to think about it again

Comment: for others encountering the same: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4537, where the author posted a link to this question, explains the issue, and a few workarounds are given (and a promise of a new release that fixes it is made). I am personally fine with clearing the build cache every time the specific dependency that caused the issue changes, so I didn't try any of the others.